# Update method doesn't update database with value

Tags: android, sql

Here is my piece of code which runs without errors, but doesn't update database:

```
ContentValues cv_lio = new ContentValues();
cv_lio.put("u_lio",1);
String where = "u_name" + "=" + 5;
db.update(table_name, cv_lio,where,null);
```

Can anyone improve my update query to work well.

Comment: @thinksteep  CREATE_TABLE_REGISTER = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+table_name+"(u_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,u_name TEXT,u_pwd TEXT,u_eadd TEXT,u_padd TEXT,u_lio INTEGER)";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was at where clause corrected code can be

---

```
ContentValues cv_lio = new ContentValues();
cv_lio.put("u_lio",1);
String where = "u_name='" + un + "'";
db.update(table_name, cv_lio,where,null);
```

---

Look for Quotes when you want to show field value like the one shown above..

Answer (score 0):

Proceed as follow :

```
ContentValues cv_lio = new ContentValues();
cv_lio.put("u_lio",1);
String where = "u_name" + " = ?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(5)};
db.update(table_name, cv_lio, where, whereArgs);
```

please refer to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) which is, I must confess, not so clear on that precise point...